# tensor products of Hopf algebras

Tags: ring-theory, tensor-products, hopf-algebras

Let $H_1,\cdots, H_n$ be Hopf algebras over the field $\mathbb{Z}_p$, $p$ prime. Then the tensor product 
$$
\bigotimes_{i=1}^nH_i
$$
is still an algebra over $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Is
$
\otimes_{i=1}^nH_i
$
still a Hopf algebra over $\mathbb{Z}_p$? How to obtain its product, unit,  coproduct, augmentation, antipode from the products, units,  coproducts, augmentations, antipodes  of $H_1,\cdots,H_n$?

Comment: The tensor product of finitely many (I suspect infinitely many, too, but I have not checked) Hopf algebras over a commutative ring is still a Hopf algebra, and its structure maps are obtained as you would you expect: E.g., if $C$ and $D$ are two coalgebras, then $C \otimes D$ becomes a coalgebra with comultiplication $\Delta_{C\otimes D} = \left(\operatorname{id}_C \otimes T \otimes \operatorname{id}_D\right) \circ \left(\Delta_C \otimes \Delta_D\right)$ where $T$ is the twist map $C \otimes D \to D \otimes C$. I'll let you guess the counity.

Comment: Dear @darijgrinberg, thanks! could you give some exact references?

Comment: Most texts on coalgebras define at least the tensor product of two coalgebras. For instance, §1.3 of http://web.mit.edu/~darij/www/algebra/HopfComb-sols.pdf (though without proof), or §3.0 in Sweedler's "Hopf algebras". Let me know if you want a detailed proof (though I find it rather straightforward).

Comment: The link I gave above should be replaced by http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/HopfComb-sols.pdf .