# How to construct irreducible representations of a Hopf algebra based on a finite non-Abelian group (beyond quantum double)?

Tags: representation-theory, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups, fusion-categories

I'm ultimately trying to construct a Hopf algebra based on a finite non-abelian group $G$ such that its irreducible representations:

1. are labeled by $g\in G$ and $\rho\in\text{irr}(G)$
2. have the fusion rules
   $$(g,\rho_i)(h,\rho_j)=\sum_kN_{i,j}^k(gh,\rho_k),$$
   where the coefficients $N_{i,j}^k$ are the fusion rules of the irreducible representations of $G$.

I believe such a Hopf algebra exists because of the statement that non-anomalous fusion categories are equivalent to representation categories of finite semisimple Hopf algebras.

The quantum double $\mathcal{D}(G)$ has irreducible representations labeled by conjugacy classes of elements $\bar a$, $a\in G$ and irreps of the centralizer $Z(a)$ of $a\in G$. This is similar to my first requirement, but with less data necessary to specify the irreducible representations. For this reason I suspect that the Hopf algebra I'm interested in is defined over $\mathbb{C}G\otimes\mathbb{C}^G$ as a vector space, as is the quantum double, but with a different multiplication.

I think it would be instructive to understand how to construct irreducible representations of the Hopf algebra of functions on a finite group $\mathbb{C}^G$, towards the goal of constructing a Hopf algebra satisfying 1 and 2. In general, I've found very few examples of explicit constructions of irreps of Hopf algebras, but one helpful resource has been section 2.2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.5479). I would appreciate any help or resources related to this smaller problem, or the larger problem above.

Comment: From your comment about "a different multiplication", what have you tried with regard to twists? The connection between Heisenberg and Drinfeld doubles being prototypical.

Comment: I've read a little about the Heisenberg double. The problem I'm running into is that even if I construct such a Hopf algebra, I'm not sure how to write down its irreps and find their fusion rules. The paper I linked states how to write down irreps of the quantum double if you already know the answer, but it seems difficult to generalize to other Hopf algebras.

Comment: My naive guess is that I can construct a tensor product Hopf algebra as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294704/tensor-product-of-hopf-algebras-and-coalgebraic-structure-on-the-dual-algebra but with $\tau$ given by $\tau:(g,h)\mapsto(h,g)$